# How to write to an existing txt file c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have created some code which creates a txt file with an initial text, however when I try to call the method again with a new msg it does not add it to the txt file. Below is my code:

```
string example = "test";
WriteToLgo(example);

public static void WriteToLog(String inputtext)
{
   string location= @"C:\Users\";
   string NameOfFile = "test.txt";
   string fileName= String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}", DateTime.Now, NameOfFile);
   string path= Path.Combine(location, fileName);
   using (StreamWriter sr= File.CreateText(path))
   {
      sr.WriteLine(inputtext);
   }
}
```

If I try and call the method a second time the new msg does not get added. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `File.CreateText`, but this `StreamWriter` overload instead:

```
//using append = true
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    sr.WriteLine(inputtext);
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Be careful with this approach, because you need to check to ensure the file exists before opening it this way for append. If the file does not exist it will exception. You can use File.AppendText(path) instead and it will append or create.

Comment: @BretLipscomb: that's not what the doc's say: `Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.`

Comment: Hmm, yep. You're right. Guess they changed that at some point or I'm thinking of a different implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @BretLipscomb: I know that feeling ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The File.CreateText only creates a new file each time, overwriting anything in it. Does not append to existing files.

You should use either File.AppendText(...) to open your existing file for appending content, or use the base StreamWriter class to open it with append options

Something like:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(path))
{
  sr.WriteLine(inputtext);
}
```

If you use the base StreamWriter class instead of File.AppendText you can use it like StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path, true); HOWEVER, you must check to see if the file exists before open it for append. Probably reccomend the File.AppendText in your case.

Comment: Why do you doubt it??

Comment: True, the `new` should be deleted. My fault for overseeing it. @Bret should remove it.

Comment: Just updated it, everyone's correct. "new" is not required in this case. Oversight on my part. That's what I get for not using intellisense.